# C++ CLI Collection initializer syntax

Tags: c++-cli

Is this supported in C++ CLI? I want to do something like the following C# example in C++ CLI

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "foo", "bar" } };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I came up with was creating an array initialized inline, then initializing the dictionary with the contents of the array in a static constructor. Something like

```
static initonly System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary<System::String^, System::String^>^ dictionary;
static initonly array<System::String^> arrayToPopulateDictionary = gcnew array<System::String^> { "foo", "bar" };

static Foo()
{
    for (int i  = 0; i < arrayToPopulateDictionary->Length; i += 2)
        listMappings->Add(arrayToPopulateDictionary[i], arrayToPopulateDictionary[i + 1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm horribly mistaken, this is simply not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely going to be possible in [C++0x](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/cpp0x.html), whether that translates to C++/CLI or not is unknown (it should do).